# Create new channel

Tags: python, botframework, microsoft-teams

I am creating a bot for microsoft teams using bot framework for python, I would like to know if a new channel can be created either through an api or directly from the bot framework.

Unfortunately I didn't find anything about it and I hope someone can help me out.

Thank you very much

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible to do this via the Bot *Framework* itself, but you can do it via the Graph API - see [Create Channel](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Of course, you bot is your own code, so the could itself call the Graph API, there's just nothing out of the box in the generic "Bot Framework" for this.